# how to get csv file records using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I'm developing a new WPF Application and I need to export records to a database from a CSV file like this one:

```
A, 22, 23, 12;B, 32, 4, 33;C, 34, 3 ,33;
```

";" means it's a line break.
So how can i get my records using LINQ? I tried this code, but I can't figure out how to line break:

```
string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(Filname);
var query = from csvline in csvlines
            let data = csvline.Split(',')
            select new
            {
                ID = data[0],
                FirstNumber = data[1],
                SecondNumber = data[2],
                ThirdNumber = data[3]
            };
```

What I want is this:

```
A 22 23 12
B 32 4  33
C 34 3  33
```

Comment: what is the value of query after this code is run? Does that actual CSV file use ; as line breaks, or is it actually \n?

Comment: Have a read of the [`.Split()` method MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) article. The last method might help give you an idea of how to handle this a bit better

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you *want* the output to be? Does the query return the records that you want? Are you just trying to get rid of the semicolons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var query = from line in File.ReadLines(filename)
    let csvLines = line.Split(';')
    from csvLine in csvLines
    where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csvLine)
    let data = csvLine.Split(',')
    select new
    {
        ID = data[0],
        FirstNumber = data[1],
        SecondNumber = data[2],
        ThirdNumber = data[3]
    };
```

Using fluent syntax:

```
var query = File.ReadLines(filename)
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(';'))
    .Where(csvLine => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csvLine))
    .Select(csvLine => new {data = csvLine.Split(',')})
    .Select(s => new
    {
        ID = s.data[0], 
        FirstNumber = s.data[1], 
        SecondNumber = s.data[2], 
        ThirdNumber = s.data[3]
    });
```

The `where` is there to prevent trying to parse the blank line that's returned by `Split` when there's a semicolon at the end of a line. An alternative would be to remove that `where` clause and replace it with

```
let data = csvLine.Split(',')
where data.Length >= 4
```

Or, make the equivalent change in the fluent syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = File.ReadLines(filename)
    .Select(csvLine => csvLine.Split(','))
    .Select(s => new
    {
        ID = s[0], 
        FirstNumber = s[1], 
        SecondNumber = s[2], 
        ThirdNumber = s[3]
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't even compile. It produces the error *Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Comment: Sorry, you don't need the first split.  I missed the part where you were replacing the newlines with a semicolon in your data.  Updated answer.